# Consulta Eloquent de multiples tablas relacionadas

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Tengo un pequeño problema con la relacion de mis tablas.

Veran, tengo 4 Tablas Medicos, Users, Role_User y role.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La tabla Medicos se relaciona con Users usando la PK de Users como FK en Medicos.

Y a su vez la tabla Users se relaciona con la tabla Role usando como tabla pivote Role_User

Ahora, estoy intentando crear una vista de una tabla, que me muestre los campos

Medicos->nombre + apellido.(Ya lo hice) Especialidad->nombre.(Ya lo hice)

Role->role(ESTO ES LO QUE NO LOGRO MOSTRAR, porque no se como hacer la relacion con eloquent)

```
@foreach ($Medicos as $Medico )
@php
   $contador=0
@endphp
<tr>
    <th scope="row">{{$contador=$contador+1}}</th>
    <td>{{$Medico->nombre}}</td>
    <td>{{$Medico->apellidos}}</td>
    <td>{{$Medico->Especialidades->nombre}}</td>
    <td>{{$Medico->centrosmedicos->nombre}}</td>

    <td>{{$Medico->Usuario->Role_User->Role->nombre}} 
    </td>

    <td> <i class="fas fa-eye"></i> Ver</td>
    <td><i class="fas fa-eye"></i> Ver</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

Lo que necesito es mostrar cual es el Rol que tiene mi usuario, pero no se como deberia hacer la relacion con Eloquent

Answer (score 0):

Para consultar múltiples relaciones primero debes asegurarte que tus modelos se encuentran correctamente relacionados, luego puedes utilizar el método `with()`.

Puedes leer más sobre [eagger loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) y [relaciones](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships)

**Ejemplo:**

```
$a = Model::with(['rel_1', 'rel_1.rel_2', 'rel_1.rel_2.rel_3'])->get();
```

Luego puedes recorrer las relaciones

```
foreach($a->rel_1 as $b) { 
    foreach($b->rel_2 as $c) { 
        foreach($c->rel_3 as $d) {
        } 
    } 
}
```